# Tomcat is redirecting URL after upload image only with ssl

Tags: ssl, grails, groovy, tomcat7

I have a tomcat running an application with Groovy on Grails. **I don't have source code of the application**, only the .war.

```
Deployment details:
Tomcat 7.
Java 1.8.
Ubuntu 16.04.
```

I deployed it over nginx at first, but, after configuring SSL(https) it started to redirect to a wrong page after upload an image. Before SSL it uploads the image and stayed in same page, as I expect it to do.

As I didn't know what configuration was causing that behavior,  changed to Apache. But, the same error occurred after SSL configuration.

In Apache, I generates a certificate with certbot (letsencrypt) and changed files as follows:

server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        SSLEnabled="true" 
        maxThreads="150" 
        scheme="https"
        secure="true"
        keystoreFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/mydomain.jks"
        keystorePass="password"
        clientAuth="false" 
        sslProtocol="TLS"
        sslVerifyClient="optional" 
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,SSLv2Hello"
    />
```

web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>app_name</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

The configuration of the form in which image is uploaded is this one:

```
<form action="/app_name/resource/save" method="post" name="myForm" on404="alert('not found!')" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
```

This form is inside a modal window.

Without SSL, after upload the image, the modal windows close normally. But, with SSL, the page is redirected to "app_name/resource/save", which is in blank. This is the action of the form.

I will appreciate any help on this. I'd like to give more details, but, seriously, I almost don't know where to start.